# OWL: property restriction based on values: is it possible at all?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege4

I look for a clearly OWL solution to define a property that is a restriction of another property, similar to an equivalent class. Restriction is based on data properties of either the domain or the range. The restricted property is definitely a subproperty, and, must be inferred.

"kid","mother","father" are Person s
father.gender = "male" data property
mother.gender = "female"

(a Male subclassOf Person = equivalent class "gender value "male")

father parentOf child ' object relation
mother parentOf child ' object relation

How to defined fatherOf property, based on parentOf and gender of father?
Clearly it is a subproperty of parentOf.

However, equivalent object property editor in Protégé does not allow setting a property query, even I do not really see if this can be solved with a property chain.

Defining fatherOf as subproperty and (manually) setting fatherOf instead of parentOf is not an option, since this family example is an oversimplified situation of a more complex scenario.

```
<Declaration>
    <Class IRI="#Person"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
    <ObjectProperty IRI="#fatherOf"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
    <ObjectProperty IRI="#parentOf"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
    <DataProperty IRI="#gender"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#father"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#kid"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#mother"/>
</Declaration>
<ClassAssertion>
    <Class IRI="#Person"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#father"/>
</ClassAssertion>
<ClassAssertion>
    <Class IRI="#Person"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#kid"/>
</ClassAssertion>
<ClassAssertion>
    <Class IRI="#Person"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#mother"/>
</ClassAssertion>
<ObjectPropertyAssertion>
    <ObjectProperty IRI="#parentOf"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#father"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#kid"/>
</ObjectPropertyAssertion>
<ObjectPropertyAssertion>
    <ObjectProperty IRI="#parentOf"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#mother"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#kid"/>
</ObjectPropertyAssertion>
<DataPropertyAssertion>
    <DataProperty IRI="#gender"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#father"/>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="&rdf;PlainLiteral">male</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>
<DataPropertyAssertion>
    <DataProperty IRI="#gender"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#mother"/>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="&rdf;PlainLiteral">female</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>
<SubObjectPropertyOf>
    <ObjectProperty IRI="#fatherOf"/>
    <ObjectProperty IRI="#parentOf"/>
</SubObjectPropertyOf>
<DataPropertyDomain>
    <DataProperty IRI="#gender"/>
    <Class IRI="#Person"/>
</DataPropertyDomain>
<DataPropertyRange>
    <DataProperty IRI="#gender"/>
    <Datatype abbreviatedIRI="xsd:string"/>
</DataPropertyRange>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you have something like the following in your data:

```
:x  :parentOf  :y .
:x  :gender  "male" .
```

and you would like to infer that:

```
:x  :fatherOf  :y .
```

I'm afraid you cannot do this in OWL. For cases like this one, you may want to rely on a rule language like SWRL, SPIN, etc. However, for the particular case of father, mother, etc, you could do the following:

- define `:hasParent` as the inverse of `:parentOf`;
- restrict the cardinality of `:hasParent` to 2;
- define `:hasFather` as the inverse of `:fatherOf`;
- make `:hasFather` a `owl:FunctionalProperty`;
- define `:hasMother` as the inverse of `:motherOf`;
- make `:hasMother` a `owl:FunctionalProperty`;
- define the class `:Man` of male people;
- define the class `:Woman` of female people;
- make `:Man` disjointWith `:Woman`;
- set the range of `:hasFather` to `:Man`;
- set the range of `:hasMother` to `:Woman`.

So the ontology looks like this (in Turtle because I'm not familiar with OWL/XML):

```
:Person  a  owl:Class;
  rdfs:subClassOf  [
    a  owl:Restriction;
    owl:onProperty  :hasParent;
    owl:cardinality  2
  ] .
:Man  a  owl:Class;
  owl:equivalentclass  [
    a  owl:Class;
    owl:intersectionOf (
      :Person
      [
         a  owl:Restriction;
         owl:onProperty  :gender;
         owl:hasValue  "male";
      ]
    )
  ] .
:Woman  a  owl:Class;
  owl:equivalentclass  [
    a  owl:Class;
    owl:intersectionOf (
      :Person
      [
         a  owl:Restriction;
         owl:onProperty  :gender;
         owl:hasValue  "female";
      ]
    )
  ] .
:gender  a  owl:DatatypeProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty .
:hasParent  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
  owl:inverseOf  :parentOf;
  rdfs:domain  :Person;
  rdfs:range  :Person .
:hasFather  a  owl:ObjectProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf  :hasParent;
  rdfs:range  :Man .
:hasMother  a  owl:ObjectProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf  :hasParent;
  rdfs:range  :Woman .
```

This should do the trick, but it's a very complicated ontology and reasoning with it may be very slow.

**Edit:** I added that `:gender` must be functional, otherwise there could be a mother who is at the same time a father and that would not work!

Comment: thanks, Antoine, the trick was to make fatherOf and motherOf subproperties of parentOf and restricting their range! the rest is left for the reasoner - though time is not irrelevant in a set of 60.000 nodes...